# Django 1.11 and Django CMS 3.4.4 MIDDLEWARE vs MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

Tags: python, django

I was doing a Django CMS setup, and had to change the MIDDLEWARE to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to get it working.

Does anyone know why MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is required in the settings.py file and not just MIDDLEWARE?

This is not a older settings file, was generated with Django 1.11

```
"""
Django settings for project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

SITE_ID = 1

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'fbyo_48g6q+w&2ewq4lazogva*tpt=4fof7xt!_uvcied&m6k$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'cms',  
    'treebeard',  
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'djangocms_admin_style',  
    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'mptt',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_video',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_snippet',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_column',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
]

THUMBNAIL_HIGH_RESOLUTION = True

THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.colorspace',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.autocrop',
    'filer.thumbnail_processors.scale_and_crop_with_subject_location',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.filters'
)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('template_1.html', 'Template One'),
    ('template_2.html', 'Template Two'),
)


ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
                'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en-us', 'English'),
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Comment: It used to be just "Middleware" not they changed it. No Big deal. The Django Team makes some adjustments sometimes. Cant tell you the specific reason why they changed the name.

Comment: @hansTheFranz `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` is the old setting, `MIDDLEWARE` is the new setting.

Comment: totally right.Sorry mixed it up. Here is the link to the docs they explain that they changed it in Django1.10 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#middleware

Comment: Support for the new-style middleware [was added in Django CMS 3.4.1](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/commit/d0f7b38f98b9c43ef0b7db46ea78f0633d1312d8). If you are running Django CMS 3.4.4 then `MIDDLEWARE` should work.

Comment: thanks guys! that makes sense